# Controlling dynamixel AX12 by Arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, arduino-mega, softwareserial

Actually, i would like to control   12 motors of AX-12 using Arduino .. I could control just 2 motors. However when i send a command to the 12 motors they don't move and one or 2 of them move randomly!

could you please help me to find solution of that ???

note :

I am using an external power with 12 Volts and 5 amp maximum